# How to tell EF4 to load specific related objects?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

For example, i have a class `Unit` it has one object `City`. `Unit` also has `Category` object. How to tell EF4 to load City object using this similar linq query, but not `Category`?

`from u in db.Units
 orderby u.Name
 select u`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indicate that those should be included, like so:

```
from u in db.Units.Include("City") 
orderby u.Name 
select u
```

I believe this can also be done like this:

```
db.Units
   .Include(u => u.City)
   .OrderBy(u => u.Name);
```